# PHP Dynamic insert function is inserting duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a function that inserts data into MYSQL database dynamically to avoid code repetition just like so :

```
function insert($table, $data)
{ 
   // connection
   global $db;

    if(!is_array($data)) die("Error : second parameter must be an array of keys and values");

    $keys   = array_keys($data);
    $values = array_values($data);

    // sql query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (";

   // if more than one column
    if(count($data) > 1)
    {
         for($i = 0; $i < count($data) -1; $i++)
         {
            $sql .= "`$keys[$i]`, ";
         }

         $sql .= "`" . end($keys) . "`) VALUES (";

         for($i = 0; $i < count($data) -1; $i++)
         {
            $sql .= ":$keys[$i], ";
         }

        $sql .=":" . end($keys) . ")";

    }else{ // only one column

        $sql .= "`$keys[0]`) VALUES(:$keys[0])";
    }

    // make keys as named placeholders
    $binds = array_map(function($elem){
        return ":".$elem;
    }, $keys);


    // combine placeholders with values
    $binds = array_combine($binds, $values);


    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt->execute($binds) ? true : false;
}
```

So Later on i can insert data just like that :

```
echo insert("users",[
    "Name"  => "Timino",
    "Email" => "admin@timino.io"
]); // result 1 inserted or 0 failed
```

However its inserting duplicate rows ?? 
when i debug the code everything looks okay

```
echo $sql;  //INSERT INTO `users` (`Name`, `Email`) VALUES (:Name, :Email)
print_r($binds) // Array
(
    [:Name] => Timino
    [:Email] => admin@timino.io
)
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Note : i have updated the code to procedural to make it easy for everyone who one to test it quickly !

Comment: did you dump the sql string before execute it ?

Comment: @MacBooc yep everything looks correct !

Comment: kinda weird, i assume that echo $db->inset isn't in loop or called 2 times ? Actually i find nothing wrong in your code

Comment: no never it is called ones

Comment: was stupid it's really weird, hmm just to be sure when you echo the $db->insert you have only 1 or 0 which is display ? edit : i mean "11" or nothing, replace your ternary by "foo" : "bar" to check

Comment: @MacBooc yep i am sure it is only one echo  and it is returning only 1 but its inserting duplicate rows i really cant get my head around hmm

Comment: i think you should check it tomorrow then :) last weird questions : no stored procedure in mysql ? no trigger after insert (php side) ?

Comment: Can you add the code calling this insert?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen its added !!

Comment: i think he meant the code before $db->insert

Comment: Yes, the code wrapping the db->insert: Something must be calling it twice since your code looks OK (nice safe against SQL injection)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen here is a spaguetti version of it and it is giving the same result two rows at ones https://codeshare.io/5XNJ98

Comment: Replace your `$db->insert(..)` call with a simple `$db->exec("INSERT ...")` and look if it still inserts twice. If so - the `insert` method has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with your script. It inserts one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you executing this code in your `index.php`?

```
echo $db->insert("users",[
    "Name"  => "Timino",
    "Email" => "admin@timino.io"
]); // result 1 inserted or 0 failed
```

It might not be a code issue.

I had a similar issue where I was testing the insert in my `index.php`, and I had a rule in my `.htaccess` that would redirect not found files to `index.php`. And when the browser tries to locate your `favicon`, it's redirected to the `index.php` which will execute the code once again.

If that's the case, you can try moving your code into another file  `test.php` and call your domain with `http://localhost/test.php` and check if it's still duplicating.

Comment: you were absolutely right !!  what happened to me is i had the same problem on both apache and nginx so that's what makes me think that it is a code problem and not a server problem but after commenting redirection rules every think works as prefered here is what was causing   the problem  for apache `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]` and for nginx `try_files /$uri /$uri /index.php?uri=$uri;`

Comment: @Timino Glad you have it figured out :)